# Magento - How to put Mageworx downloads block outside of magento?

Tags: php, magento

How to put `Mageworx` downloads block outside of magento?

For Example:

```
{{block type="downloads/link" id="5,6,7" title="Files"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost any Magento blocks can be programmed this way:

```
   <?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php'); // don't forget to replace app/Mage.php with the actual path to your Magento
    $mage = Mage::app();
    // create the block
    $block = $mage->getLayout()->createBlock('downloads/link', '', array('id' => '1,5,6,7', 'title' => 'Files'));
    // output the block   
    echo $block->toHtml();
```

Please note that most likely you will face typical issues of such an  "ouside of Magento" output, such as absence of scripts, styles, images.

In this case, everything is connected in a similar way. All dependencies can be found in the corresponding layout.